# How to access captured arguments / closure of python instance method objects?

Tags: python, closures, weak-references

The idea is to implement the Observer pattern in a non leaking / autocleanup fashion. Therefor the instance method objects should be removed when the the associated object is cleaned up by the gc.
My original idea was to only store weak references to the instance method objects with a finalizer to call a cleanup routine.

```py
class Observeable:
    def __init__(self):
        self._callbacks: list = []
        self._dirty = False

    def add_callback(self, callback):
        finalize(callback, self._set_dirty)
        self._callbacks.append(ref(callback))

    def trigger_callbacks(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._dirty:
            self._cleanup_callbacks()
        for callback in self._callbacks:
            callback()(*args, **kwargs)

    def _set_dirty(self):
        self._dirty = True

    def _cleanup_callbacks(self):
        for callback in self._callbacks:
            if not callback():
                self._callbacks.remove(callback)
        self._dirty = False
```

However as it turns out the approach is conceptually flawed as the lifetime of the instance method object is not bound to the associated object.

This leads me to the idea to extract the self parameter from the closure of the instance method objects and bind to its lifetime. This can of course be done by passing a second argument to add_callback, however it would be cleaner to extract it from the closure.

As I wasn't able to find any usefull information of how the closure is stored in the function object, I have a few questions for you guys.

1. Is my thinking even right? Storing a instance method objects will prevent the behind object from being cleaned up automatically, right?
2. Is it possible to extract the self parameter / general closure from function objects?
3. Is there a more "official" name for function objects? The python docu also just called it like that, however there seems to be no usefull information about its more low level implementation available.

I hope my problem / questions are clear, thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I also just got the thought that when the function objects of a method stores a reference to the origin object then this will prevent it from ever being cleaned up anyway, no mater whether the function is a only a weak ref or not. Therefor I guess such a auto cleanup Observeable without manual unsubscribing is not possible at all?

Comment: A function object doesn't have a `self` object as one of its attributes. Only a `method` object has the `self` object as one of its attributes, though I'm not sure about the exact name of that attribute.

Comment: Does your callback need to be stored as a reference to a function, or does it need to be stored as a reference to a method?

Comment: @fountainhead yes, I'm only talking about function objects to methods, sry if that was not clear

Comment: I feel you should be storing a reference to the method object rather than the function object. (What if two instances of the same class want to add the same callback function, to the same Observable object?) As for your original problem of clean-up,, perhaps your subscriber object could call an 'unsubscribe()'  method (or `remove_callback()` method) of the Observable, perhaps in the `__del()__` method of the subscriber object.

Comment: I think we got a different naming for things here. In my understanding a method is also a function, so a "method object" is a function object with a captured reference to the origin object. So yes I'm already storing a "method object". Other then that a remove_callback is of course the trivial implementation, however then the origin object has to be manually deleted, as the reference count of the origin object will never reach 0 when a "method object" exists, right? I'm not sure how the reference is stored in the method object and that was sort of the original question.

Comment: [The doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) says that the origin object is stored as a read-only attribute called `__self__` in an instance method object. (Search for "Instance methods" on that page)

Comment: yes, your question should be talking about "instance method objects" or just "method objects", rather than "function objects". I suggest you do make the edit. I guess that answers your Question3. As for your other 2 questions,: (1) Yes, storing a reference to the method object will prevent the associated class instance from being cleaned up automatically (2) As [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) says, you can access it as the read-only attribute `__self__` in the method object.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. The data model docu is very informative, I didn't knew it existed.

Comment: I will edit the post. Also thanks for answering all questions, now everything is clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fountainhead mostly answered it with his comments so I will summarize it shortly.

A function object from a method is officially called "instance method object" (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html, search for method object)

Therefor 1. it will prevent the associated object from being cleaned up by the gc.
2. It can be accessed by `__self__` and 3. is already answered above.

To make the Observable Class working like I intended it, I basically save the function name and a weakref to `__self__` and then call it with `getattr()`. Works like a charm!

```
from weakref import finalize, ref
from functools import partial


class Observeable:
    def __init__(self):
        self._methods: list = []
        self._functions: list = []
        self._dirty = False

    def add_callback_methode(self, callback):
        """
        Adds a callback from a method.
        The callback will automatically be cleanup,
         when its associated objects gets out of scope,
          therefor also not preventing the gc from cleaning it up.
        """
        finalize(callback.__self__, self._set_dirty)
        self._methods.append((callback.__name__, ref(callback.__self__)))

    def trigger_callbacks(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Forwards the given args and kwargs to all callbacks"""
        if self._dirty:
            self._cleanup_callbacks()
        for callback in self._methods:
            getattr(callback[1](), callback[0])(*args, **kwargs)

    def _set_dirty(self):
        self._dirty = True

    def _cleanup_callbacks(self):
        for callback in self._methods:
            if not callback[1]():
                self._methods.remove(callback)
        self._dirty = False
```